# Cannot find data for drupal business users

Tags: mysql, drupal

I am volunteering for an association that uses a web site backed up by drupal. I am not very knowledgeable about the custom database structure but I have been trying to locate the addresses for "business" users using SQL queries. I can find easily addresses for regular users in the "field_data_field_postal_address". I assume they use a custom module and form to store addresses but I cannot locate the table or records for users.

For regular users , I write the following and it works perfectly.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM users u
  JOIN profile p
    ON u.uid = p.uid
  JOIN field_data_field_postal_address a
    ON a.entity_id = p.pid
```

For the businesses, I use the same query but have to join to a custom table to filter out for just businesses and it returns nothing.

```
 SELECT * FROM users
 INNER JOIN profile ON users.uid = profile.uid
 INNER JOIN field_data_field_postal_address ON profile.pid = field_data_field_postal_address.entity_id
 inner join field_data_field_is_business on field_data_field_is_business.entity_id = profile.pid
```

I feel like I am either missing a mapping table between business and users or that there is a separate table where business addresses are located. I was just wondering if anyone recognizes some type of pattern in the table that could point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: Try to get out of the habit of using `SELECT *`. Instead name, and qualify, only the columns you actually want returned.

Comment: Which one is the "mapping table"?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for it.

Comment: The mapping table that I am aware of if the "profile" table. I am looking for table that joins user of type "business" and their addresses. Let me know if this is not helping.